# SSRS Recursive Hierarchy for Bill of Material

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am trying to create an SSRS report for a Bill of Materials (product structure) with parent child recursive grouping to enable drill down to multiple levels.

I have achieved the goal of doing this with a recursive CTE and including a parent recursive reference to the Child group in SSRS.

This produces a very pretty report that allows for drill down to levels with indents and levels and everything! Just one problem.....

By grouping on the Component to get the recursive technology to work, the result set of my CTE which has 37 rows gets truncated down to 32 due to multiple rows getting merged because part numbers can be the same while used on more than one part.

I could finally solve this by
Adding a column to my select statement; Parent+'-'+Component As PKey, and group on this and leave the recursive parent and it should worked (Now it properly shows duplicated parts).

**My problem is now I lost the drill down functionality.**

Although I toggle the visibility of detail row to component, by any reason, the small + and - disappear and I no more can drill down.

Any suggestion how this can be solved.

Assume this is my test table

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE(Component NVARCHAR(20),Parent NVARCHAR(20),Qty INT,Descr     NVARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES 
('child1','parent1',0,'Desc 1'),
('child1','parent2',0,'Desc 1'),
('child2','parent2',3,'Desc 1'),
('parent1','GrandParent1',0,'Desc 1'),
('parent2','GrandParent1',0,'Desc 1'),
('parent3','GrandParent1',0,'Desc 1'),
('GrandParent1','GrandParent1',0,'Desc 1')
SELECT  Component + Parent as  PKey,* FROM @Test
```

in SSRS I created a detail group, group by Pkey and recursive parent(In advanced tab) as Parent.

the visibility of the details group is toggle by Component currently and not working.

Comment: Share the dataset you have and sample data if possible.

Comment: I saw a post somewhere else that proposed the same problem, I am using  a sample table from here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f8b8a81a-be3f-4ad7-8f24-6f58263b1e19/ssrs-recursive-hierarchy-for-bill-of-material?forum=sqlreportingservices since the issue is the same

Comment: I edited my post and incorporate a sample table and explaine how I achieved recursive hierarchy in SSRS.

Comment: I don't get how you get stuck, please add screenshot of the tablix you get so far and the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I do not entirely understand what your problem is but I come with a possible solution here.

Using the dataset you added to the original question I've created a tablix grouped by Parent and toggled the additional columns visibility to that field.

Create a tablix with the following data arrangement:

[image]

Select the `Component`, `Qty` and `Descr` cells (below headers) and press `F4` to see the properties windows.

In the `Visibility` submenu set the properties as the below screenshot.

[image]

It will preview the following tablix:

[image]

> Initially it will hide the details due to `True` setting in `Hidden`
>   property.

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: thank you Alejandro for your time. the problem with what you produced is that it does not show hierarchy. I modified the table in my original post so it can be more clear.

Comment: In this table you can see child1 is child of both parent1 and parent2 and parent1 and parent2 themselves are children of grandparent1.

Comment: with your method, hierarchy is not displayed. parent 1 and parent 2 can not be drilled to children immediately from grandarent1. unfortunately I am new here and dont know how to attach pictures. but if you check here <https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255243.aspx> , you will see what I mean

Comment: with the method presented in msdn I can show the hierarchy properly. the problem though is this method will eliminate repeating children. Meaning children 1 repeated just once below parent1 which is not true. it should be also shown under parent2.

Comment: I finally could solve this by creating a key (component + parent) and group based on that. this will solve the elimination of repeating children. However it cost me the drill down functionality. I no more can drill down to each component.

Comment: @FatemehShakhsesalim, I still don't understand what is your desired result. Do you want to drill down in multiple levels, i.e. _drill down from grand to parent and from it drill to child_? Please clarify what is your expected tablix and its toggled behaviour.

Comment: Yes exactly and that cant not be achieved with the method you presented first hand. it has to be done through Recursive Hierarchy Group which is explained here:

Comment: I want something like this: grandparent-->parent--->child                                                    what you produced is more like grandparent--->parent  and parent-->child